# How can insert a class to navigation menu on scroll while scrolling certain areas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert a class while I scroll certain elements with custom data attribute and depending on  this attribute to insert a class to the navigation menu. While the .product(s) is visible to the viewport I want an active class to the menu and when the data-attribute of the products change.

I want to achieve something like this https://www.kunkalabs.com/mixitup/docs/configuration-object/

````
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .product {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 20px;
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
            height:300px;
        }


    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li class="menu-list" data-category="1">Category 1</li>
        <li class="menu-list" data-category="2">Category 2</li>
        <li class="menu-list" data-category="3">Category 3</li>
        <li class="menu-list" data-category="4">Category 4</li>
        <li class="menu-list" data-category="5">Category 5</li>
        <li class="menu-list" data-category="6">Category 6</li>
    </ul>



    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="product" data-category-id="1">product 1</div>
        <div class="product" data-category-id="2">product 2</div>
        <div class="product" data-category-id="2">product 3</div>
        <div class="product" data-category-id="2">product 4</div>
        <div class="product" data-category-id="3">product 5</div>
        <div class="product" data-category-id="3">product 7</div>
        <div class="product" data-category-id="3">product 8</div>
        <div class="product" data-category-id="4">product 9</div>
        <div class="product" data-category-id="4">product 10</div>


    </div>


    <script>

            $.fn.isInViewport = function() {
                var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
                var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

                var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

                console.log(viewportBottom);

                return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
            };

            $(window).on('scroll', function() {

                $('.product').each(function() {
                    var activeColor = $(this).data('category-id');

                    if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
                    /* $('menu-list' + activeColor).addClass('bold'); */
                    $('menu-list').css("height","600px");
                    } else {
                    /* $('menu-list' + activeColor).removeClass('bold'); */
                    $('.product').css("background-color","green");
                    }
                });
            });



    </script>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of listening to scroll event you should have a look at [Intersection Observer (IO)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). This was designed to solve problems like yours. And it is much more performant than listening to scroll events and then calculating the position yourself.

Here is a quick example on how to change the classlist of the header once a section scrolls into view (or is outside of the view)

You can adjust this of course to use the correct threshold parameters for your IO to get the desired result. And you don't have to toggle the classlist on the header you can use any element you like. I used plain Javascript in the example but feel free to also use jQuery inside the IO callback if that makes it easier for you.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.products');
const config = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, self) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Feel free to use jQuery here.
    var headerEl = document.querySelector('header');
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      // if the section is intersecting with viewport
      headerEl.classList.add(entry.target.dataset.header);
    } else {
      // section is not visible within viewport
      headerEl.classList.remove(entry.target.dataset.header);
    }
  });
}, config);

sections.forEach(section => {
  observer.observe(section);
});
```

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.g-100vh {
height: 100vh
}

header {
  min-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
}
  
header.products-header {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<header>
 <p>Header Content </p>
</header>
<section class="g-100vh" style="background-color:darkblue;">
    <h1> NOT PRODUCTS </h1>
</section>

<section class="g-100vh" style="background-color:darkblue;">
    <h1> NOT PRODUCTS </h1>
</section>

<section class="g-100vh products" style="background-color:lightgrey;" data-header="products-header">
    <h1> PRODUCTS </h1>
</section>

<section class="g-100vh" style="background-color:lightgrey;">
    <h1> NOT PRODUCTS </h1>
</section>

<section class="g-100vh" style="background-color:lightgrey;">
    <h1> NOT PRODUCTS </h1>
</section>
```